# Find an element of order $p$ in a non-abelian group $G$ of order $p^3$ where $p$ is an odd prime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> **Problem.** Let $p$ be an odd prime and $G$ be a *non-abelian* group of order $p^3$. Suppose there exists an element $x\in G$ of order $p^2$. Find an element $y\in G\setminus\langle x\rangle$ of order $p$.

It is true, by Cauchy's theorem or some other theorems, that $G$ has an element of order $p$. However, we are not sure whether it lies in $\langle x\rangle$ because $x^p,x^{2p},\ldots,x^{(p-1)p}$ all have order $p$.

I tried another approach: The number of element in $G$ of order $p^2$ must be a power of $$\varphi(p^2)=p(p-1),$$ where $\varphi$ is the Euler's totient function. There are $p^3-1$ non-identity elements in $G$. We have $$p^3-1=p(p-1)(p+1)+p-1=(p+1)\varphi(p^2)+p-1.$$ This also implies that $G$ has an element of order $p$, but the remainder $p-1$ is problematic as we already have $p-1$ elements of order $p$ above.

Does anyone have good ideas on this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nonabelian group of order $p^3$, we must have $[G,G] = Z(G)$ and $|Z(G)|=p$.

So, for any $a,b \in G$, using $ba= ab[b,a]$, and $[b,a] \in Z(G)$, we get $(ab)^p = a^pb^p[b,a]^{p(p-1)/2} = a^pb^p$, since $p$ is odd.

Let $y \in G \setminus \langle x \rangle$. Then, since $G$ is nonabelian, $y$ cannot have order $p^3$, so $y^p =x^{ap}$ for some $a$. Then $(x^{-a}y)^p = x^{-ap}x^{ap}=1$, so $x^{-a}y$ has order $p$.

(Note that this result is false for $p=2$ and the quaternion group $Q_8$ is a counterexample.)

Comment: Thanks. I also found this solution from K. Conrad's paper: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/groupsp3.pdf just before. I was trying to understand the proof and planned to write it if nobody answered my question then. Anyway, thank you for your help :)

Comment: Just one more comment, people can find the proof of $(ab)^n=a^nb^n[b,a]^{n(n-1)/2}$ from this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77149/proving-a-commutator-identity-for-groups.

Comment: Bernhard, you need not write it again here if it is already in one of Keith Conrad's notes. Of course, you can ask about details of the proof, which remain unclear.

Comment: Do we really need lots of links for this? Isn't it preferable understand why this is true? To transform $(ab)^n$ to $a^nb^n[b,a]^{n(n-1)/2}$, you apply the rule $ba \to ab[b,a]$ $n(n-1)/2$ times and use the fact that $[b,a]$ commutes with $a$ and $b$.